A detail on the solution to the wave equation, by separation of variables method.
In a book about partial differential equations, which I'm reading, the author states, when considering a solution to the wave-equation, by the separable variables method, of the form $u(t,x) = w(t)v(x)$:

if the domain of the solution is connected then $$\frac{w''(t)}{w(t)} = \frac{v''(x)}{v(x)}$$ only happens  if and only if both $v(x)$ and $w(t)$ are constant functions.

Why is that? Intuitively, I may grant that... but formally, how would one go about this?

LHS is independent of $x$ and RHS is independent of $t$ and they are equal. So they cannot depend on either $x$ or $t$.

@geetha290krm yes, I get it... But would there be a more formal way to go, or would this type of reasoning suffice for most purposes?

Here is a formal proof. Denote LHS by $f(t)$ and RHS by $g(x)$. Then, $f(t)=g(x)$ for all $t$ and $x$. Fix a point $(a,b)$ in the $(t,x)-$ domain. Then, for any $t$, $f(t)=g(b)$ (by taking $x=b$). Thus, all values of $f$ are equal to the constant $g(b)$. Similarly, $g(x)=f(a)$ for all $x$, so $g$ is also a constant. This proves that the two sides of the equation are constants. But you cannot say that $w$ and $v$ are constants. You can have, for example, $w(t)=\sin t$ and $v(x)=\sin x$.

So you just proved that $w''/w$ and $v''/v$ is constant. The OP claimed that $w$ and $v$ would then be constant.  With just these equations functions $v(\tau)$ and $w(\tau)$ of type $Ae^\tau+Be^{-\tau}$ will satisfy that $w''/w$ and $v''/v$ are constant without being constant themselves.

@Maksim Thanks. I misread the question. I have edited my answer.  I think OP mis-quoted the book.
